Session sometime Getting null value after redirect a page in C# ASP.NET Core Razor pages
My project fully builds in ASP.NET Core Razor pages, an e-commerce site. I have used so many sessions in the project like
string CartDatass = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionShoppingCartAfterConfirm");

Sometimes, sessions is null when trying to get data using .GetString() from it. After reloading the page 2, 3 times, the session provides the expected data again. Why?

You could provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can help you troubleshoot, based on the description we can only give you advices but not solutions. Your issue could be the page rendered before the session retrieves the data. Check the log to debug. Some other reasons could be session timed out or cookie issues.
